# regular expression - dollar signs within border characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

In php, I am trying to match two consecutive dollar signs surrounded by border characters, but I can't seem to figure out the pattern. Here are example strings I want to match:

```
$string = '$$';
$string = ' $$ ';
$string = "\n$$\n";
```

Here are the patterns I have tried:

```
$pattern = '/\b\$\$\b/';     // First attempt at escaping dollar signs
$pattern = '/\b\\\$\\\$\b/'; // Maybe backslashes need to be escaped
$pattern = '/\b$$\b/';       // Maybe dollar signs shouldn't be escaped
$pattern = "/\b\$\$\b/";     // Maybe we need double quotes for special characters
$pattern = "/\b\\\$\\\$\b/"; // Double quotes and double-escaping
```

None of the above patterns return any matches when running:

```
preg_match($pattern, $string);
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I'd assume because `$` is not a word character, and `\b` is a word boundary therefore not being matched. What are you counting as a "border character"?

Comment: I think you're onto something. A space or line break is not considered a word boundary when next to a dollar sign. If I cannot use word boundaries at all for this, is there still a way to match the example strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the OP and @JonStirling basically cracked this problem before I posted this answer.  Your very first pattern `\b\$\$\b` is correct, at least from the point of view of properly escaping dollar sign.  The issue is that word boundaries mainly deal with boundaries between words and non words.  Since dollar sign is not a word character, `\b` is not behaving as you want.

Here is an alternative which uses lookarounds as a proxy for word boundaries:

```
$string = ' $$';
$pattern = '/(?<=\s|^)\$\$(?=\s|$)/';
echo preg_match($pattern, $string, $match);
```

The logic here is that we check for either whitespace or the start/end of the string, on both sides of the dollar signs.

Comment: It works, thank you! I'll probably need to comment this code in our project because it's a bit confusing (to me at least).

Comment: I think the ultimate cause of this is that regex was originally intended to deal with text/words.  So things like `\b` are meant for separating words from everything else.  But, in your case, you sort of want a boundary logic which can work for symbols.

Comment: Exactly Thank you again for the answer and clear explanation.